# Google map not working in android app via appium (Java)

Tags: android, mobile, google-maps-api-3, appium

I am getting brown screen while loading Google Map (Please refer the attached screenshot for the same) from Appium and where Application is installing via Appium.

[Click here for image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zUPXx.png)

Also we have tried with below different options.However still issue is not resolved.

Checked with Desired Capabilities for "noSign" as true and false.
We have resigns apk with another certificate (using this procedure : http://www.thetestingworld.com/resigning-apk-file/)
Checked with below Desired Capabilities

- useKeystore
- keystorePath
- keystorePassword

So if anyone having resolution for this issue then please share steps with required details for the same.

Note: If we are manually installing the Application on device and after that opening the Google Map via Appium then it is successfully loading and opening.

Comment: your screenshot is not visible

Comment: Please click on link : "Click here for image"

Comment: Is there any error showing in logcat ?

Comment: Not getting any useful information from logcat

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this may happens with resigning . 
On Android, if we resign the app. This may break functionality that depends on the app signature, such as the Google Maps Android API.

You can look into this thread for the solution.
Case: Calabash resign the android app and the google maps stop loading.
[Cannot load Google maps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30242095/cannot-load-google-maps)

Answer (score -1):

You must use Android Capability noSign = true.